# Chihuahua ALWAYS gets excited and pees

Tags: dogs, urination

So I have to start this off by saying I may have not properly trained my Chihuahua from the get go and it's most likely the reason he's doing this here, but I figured I'd ask for help anyway in case there are some specific pointers that I can follow.

Long story short, I have a ~1 year old Chihuahua. My previous dogs (german shepherds and labradors) were so much easier to train and never made mistakes for this long. My Chihuahua always goes to his designated area to pee and poop with no problem. However, usually if I leave the house and come home a few hours later, he's so excited that he pees the minute I greet him. I've sort of found a workaround to this by not greeting him for awhile after I get home. Works well for the most part.

Now when I get ready to take him outside (which I try to do on a daily basis), he usually pees the minute I tell him to sit (so I can put the leash on him). Very annoying and usually causes me to have to stop and go grab paper towels to clean up. Make him sit again and it's the same thing.

Is it just that I don't take my dog out enough or something? I recall reading that some dogs do this and some dogs don't, but that most dogs will break out of this as they grow older.

Comment: Is there any history of punishment upon peeing?

Comment: Well, I usually just tell him "no" while he's doing it and I'll ignore him for a few minutes until hopefully he calms down more.

Comment: Since you don't greet him I guess you've already tried not "rewarding" his excitement with attention at all?

Comment: Exactly. I avoid it all the time actually.